# cellforRowAtIndexPath efficiency?

Tags: ios, performance, tableview, cells

Whenever I scroll my tableview it is very laggy. I think it has to do with how I am loading up my cells. I use UINib (5.0+) whenever I can while still providing backwards compatibility. Then I load my custom cell's labels and images with items from a NSDictionary from a NSArray which is loaded from NSUserDefaults in the ViewDidLoad.

Is there any way to improve the efficiency of this cellForRowAtIndexPath?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        if ([self labelCellNib]) {
            [[self labelCellNib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        } else {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        cell = [self CustomTableCell];
        [self setCustomTableCell:nil];
    }
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSData *data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OCRImage"];
    cell.previewPicture.image = [self roundCorneredImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] radius:60];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.titleLabel.delegate = self;

    cell.dateLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Date"];

    if (indexPath.row%2) {
        cell.backgroundImage.image = firstImage;
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundImage.image = secondImage;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Edit:

```
- (UIImage*)roundCorneredImage: (UIImage*)orig radius:(CGFloat) r {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(orig.size, NO, 0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size} 
                                cornerRadius:r] addClip];
    [orig drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, orig.size}];
    UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

**Edit2**: These are the lines that are causing the lag:

```
NSData *data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OCRImage"];
cell.previewPicture.image = [self roundCorneredImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] radius:60];
```

Comment: Use instruments to identify the hotspots and do not assume runtime behavior.

Comment: Look at the comment below that I made for @jesse bunch I explain the bottlenecks

Comment: Check this answer. AWERSOME: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334782/1381708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of my notes after looking at your code:

1. Is `roundCorneredImage:radius:` caching the result? If not, executing CG calls for every cell would surely present a bottleneck. **Updated:** Use instruments to be sure, but it might be faster (memory allowing) to store the processed `UIImage` in a collection so that you can pull it out again the next time that method is called with the same parameters.
2. All of your `UIImage`s could be declared elsewhere and then presented in this method. Your current code instantiates a new `UIImage` for each cell which can also bottleneck your scrolling. **Updated:** Since `Image1.png` and `Image2.png` are basically static, you could declare them in your interface or as a static ivar and then just assign them to the background image rather than instantiating `UIImage` each time.
3. It may be faster to subclass `UITableViewCell` and instantiate that instead of reaching into `UINib`. Also, you'd then be able to separate your layout/data logic from the delegate method. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/707bff0b7388dedae7b7) of what I did in my `UITableViewCell` subclass. Basically, I store the entity with the cell and the cell knows about it's labels and such. This keeps the cell layout logic out of my data source code.
4. It looks like you're using an `NSDictionary` as your data source. If you have a lot of objects in that dictionary, it may be considerable faster to use `CoreData` and an `NSFetchedResultsController`. [Here's a good post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) on the matter. **Updated:** Ok, that shouldn't be an issue.

-

### Edit

So if you removed all of this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [myArray objectForKey:@"OCRImage"];
cell.previewPicture.image = [self roundCorneredImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] radius:60];

if (indexPath.row%2) {
    cell.backgroundImage.image = firstImage;
}
else {
    cell.backgroundImage.image = secondImage;
}
```

and it still lags, let's look at your constructors...what do these lines do?

```
cell = [self CustomTableCell];
[self setCustomTableCell:nil];
```

Also, you're not using any transparent images or anything in your table cell are you? Those have been known to cause drawing lag...

-

### Edit #2

If you strip down to this, what happens?

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    if ([self labelCellNib]) {
        [[self labelCellNib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    } else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    cell = [self CustomTableCell];
    [self setCustomTableCell:nil];
}

cell.titleLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

Comment: #1. I added the roundCorneredImage method. #2.What do you mean by presented in this method? How would I do that? #4. I only have 4 objects in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok now I updated my code, I made ivars for Image1 and Image2 and declared the UIImage imageName in my viewWillAppear, then I set it like so in my updated code above. Also will #3 really fix my efficiency or is that just for organization purposes?

Comment: I have no idea. You'll have to try it and see if it's faster. For the second part about the layout logic, that's just for organization.

Comment: #2 didn't make it any better unfortunately. #1 I took it out temporarily along with the images and the tableview still lags. Looking at @Caleb's post, could I adjust my code to anything to what he is saying to make my tableview scroll without lag?

Comment: My images are not transparent, they are just colors that are not available with UIColor. And to be honest, I am not too sure what those 2 lines do, I thought it was for efficiency purposes but maybe not? I got that from a tutorial.

Comment: Ahh I know what they do. Since you're loading from a Nib you have to set the IVar to Nil and it will automatically be replaced with the cell loaded from the Nib.

Comment: Oh ok I see, so that is not an issue :p Any other ideas?

Comment: I made a few typos in my original code that may make some differences, take a look at the updated code. The NSDictionary and NSData lines were the ones that were wrong.

Comment: But if you remove all of that, it doesn't make a difference? I could certainly see instantiating a UIImage from a data stream stored in a dictionary being the culprit.

Comment: I didn't test it since there was a typo in my original code, now that I updated it, what do you want me to take out to test? I took out the background image code and that still causes lag if thats what your asking.

Comment: Update your code to look like Edit #2 and see if that helps. Let's start stripping things out until it starts working without lag.

Comment: Ok so just setting the titleLabel from the NSDictionary value and nothing else seems to have no lag. And setting the dateLabel seems to not have any lag either. And setting the background Images still has no lag, so the thing that seems to cause the lag is 2 lines which I will post in my original post

Comment: OK, I would suggest then processing the images outside of the table view and storing those in the dictionary rather than the raw data. Then, just load the image from the dictionary.

Comment: Would it be because the images are too large? I scale them to the width and height of the screen.

Comment: It could be that there is a lot of data being processed or that the actual conversion from raw bytes to a UIImage is slowing it down. Likewise, it could be that the rounding of the corners by Core Graphics is slowing it down.

Comment: SUCCESS! I just did my UIImage resize and rounding corners in another method prior to adding it to the cellForRow and it scrolls very fast! Thanks for all your help! Upvoted and Accepted!!!!

Comment: One more thing, you can get any color with UIColor, see colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:

Comment: I know its just easier going into PhotoShop and choosing the color I want that way then messing with values :)

Answer (score 3):

As @Till said in a comment, you should launch your app in Instruments (Product -> Profile in Xcode), and select the CPU -> Time Profiler instrument.

Then, scroll around over the place for a few seconds, then hit the Record toolbar icon in instruments to close your app. You will be able to see the scrolling section because CPU usage will probably be pinned at 100% (unless it's slow because of network activity problem).

Click on the timeline after the start of the high CPU activity area, and click the "start inspection range" toolbar button, then click before the end of the high CPU activity area and click the "stop inspection range" toolbar button.

You can now drill down into the call tree view at the bottom of the window to figure out exactly where all your CPU usage is. In my experience it's usually easier to find the problem if you turn off "invert call tree" option on the left.

Performance bugs can be very hard to find, and sometimes a line of code that is obviously slow actually isn't causing any problems at all. The only way to fix performance issues without wasting time is to use Instruments.

Comment: The only things that are taking up a lot of time is these 2 things. both 840.0 ms. #1 Coregraphics - argb32_sample_argb32 #2 Coregraphics - argb32_image_mark

Comment: What are the percentages of those 2 things? Normally there's a single line somewhere consuming ~90% of the CPU time or a couple of things consuming 40% each. If your CPU is mostly idle, then you must be reading from the disk or there may be network activity. I suspect the problem is `imageWithData:`, `roundCorneredImage:` or `imageNamed:`, and all of these should be done in `awakeFromNib` or similar. But you need to confirm it with instruments before making that change, as it may not be the problem.

Comment: 49.7% on both. How would I do roundCorneredImage in the awakeFromNib if each image in each cell needs to be rounded? I just can't see the logistics :\

Comment: If both are 49.7% then that is your performance problem. You need to get them down to about to 0%. The cellForRow method should be very fast, as in 1 or 2 milliseconds fast. Either load all the images and apply rounded corners in awakeFromNib, or do what you are doing now but cache the images in an NSMutableDictionary or similar.

Comment: I figured out the issue, in my comments with @Jesse, I fixed it by resizing my UIImages to be smaller.

Comment: Resizing them to be smaller isn't good enough. Even a small image resize operation is still going to consume excessive CPU. This delegate is called while drawing to the screen, and needs to be extremely efficient. On older devices it will probably still be noticeably slow, and on faster ones it will reduce battery life by pushing the CPU unnecessarily hard. You need to make sure you only ever perform these operations *once*. Do not perform them hundreds of of times for each image, which is what you're doing now.

Comment: I don't resize in the cellforrow, I resize the images in another method prior to the images even getting to the tablview.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you've set the reuse identifier for your cell to the same thing that you've specified in your code, i.e. `@"Cell"`. If they don't match, then you won't be reusing cells properly, and probably spending a lot more time creating cells than necessary.

If you are properly recycling cells, then you should take a look at the code *after* the `if (cell == nil) {...}` block. You'll be skipping that entire block once the table has created enough cells to fill the screen (and maybe one or two more), so most of the time attributable to this method while scrolling will be due to the following code. It'd be interesting to know what `myArray` is, and if it's actually an array, what the `objectForKey:` method does. Nothing else there *looks* like it should take a long time, but the best way to find out where the cycles are going is to profile your code in Instruments.

Comment: Ok I fixed the cellIdentifier issue, but it is still laggy. myArray is a array loaded for NSUserDefaults that contains NSDictionarys.

Comment: Ok so if my code after if (cell == nil) is bad, what should it be instead to make it more efficient?

Comment: Again, profile your code in Instruments to determine where your code is spending the most time. If it looks like a particular line such as  the `roundCorneredImage:` call is responsible for the lag, confirm that by removing the line. If you comment that line out, does the problem go away? If yes, then find a faster way to do the work, find a way to do it less often, or find a way to do it at a different time. Finally, profile in Instruments again to confirm that you've solved the problem.